# Error /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/colord/colord what does this mean?

Tags: 12.04

Running 12.04, just turned on my laptop and got this error message, and I have no idea what this means or if there's a fix? Is this something I should be worried about? Thanks for any help in advance.

"Sorry Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error.

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/colord/colord"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be to do with *printing*, I don't think this is fundamental to the use of your system if you don't own a printer. If I were you I'd want to fix it though.

I would search it in google.

I found this, http://wilkiecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/colord-error-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04/

```
 sudo ldconfig
 sudo dpkg -r colord
 sudo apt-get check
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

Comment: I don't use a printer at all for this laptop. I ran those commands, but nothing turned up when I did that

Comment: Did, you look at the second link? 

http://journalxtra.com/linuxsanity/fixing-the-dreaded-errors-were-encountered-while-processing-errors-1495/

Comment: Yes I did look at the second link, spent some time looking over it and it seemed a bit more advanced than something that I'd used to. The colord error has only happened the one time on my laptop, but if it ever happens again, I'll have to try to figure out what the second link is trying to say because there's a lot of steps to do for that.

Comment: Had the same error. Your solution fixed it, thank you!